# Python string storage

Tags: python-2.7

when i store 'Python' in A and try to print A[-6] it prints P but why it shows error when i try to print A[6] .
 Also it prints 'P' for both A[-0] and A[0] but result for A[1] is 'y' and A[-1] is 'n' .

Comment: google for python string indexing. - http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/strings.html

Comment: This is just a general lack of reading docs situation.

Comment: @anishsane: Did you link to python 1.5? :-) I guess it makes a point for sure. Info has been around for some time.

Comment: LOL! I just googled for "python string indexing". Did not really checked the link path, except that it was on docs.python.org. As such the basics of python strings should not change :-)

Answer (score 2):

Python **strings** are python **lists** of chars (sort of an array of chars), so they share a *numbering scheme*... and also you can think of your string as ['P','y','t','h','o','n']

Lists numbering scheme: numbering starts with 0 as in C: so A[0]=='P'(first element),...,A[5]=='n'(last element) and that's why A[6] is out of bound - same as in C.

negative indexing is a Python feature: you can access python lists from the end - numbering from the end starts with -1, so A[-1] is the last element in the list, in your case A[-1]==A[5]=='n'; then obviously A[-2]=='o', etc...  A[-5]=='y' and A[-6]=='P'(first element).

A[0]==A[-0], just by definition, I assume...

Comment: "Python strings are python lists of chars" - Not quite, but something alike.